# TypeScript Generic filter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want filter any have X Object in interface

```
function hello<T extends keyof I>(type:T,value:I[T]["X"]):void

interface I{
    A:{
        X:any
    }
    B:{
        Y:any
    }
    C:{
        X:any
        Y:any
    }
}
```

I just hope type is `A|C`

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?

function hello<T extends keyof Pick<I, 'A'|'B'>>

Comment: Thx, But can I filter have X

Comment: Ah I see, so you want only properties that have X. I will write an answer for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are looking for this?

```
type FilterKeysToObject<T, V> = {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: T[K]
};


interface I{
    A:{
        X:any
    }
    B:{
        Y:any
    }
    C:{
        X:any
        Y:any
    }
}

type WithX = FilterKeysToObject<I, {X: any}>;

function hello<K extends keyof WithX>(type:WithX,value:WithX[K]['X']):void {

}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgaQiAzgFQPYDyARgFYQDGwAPDgDRQBqAfFALxQDeAUAJADaaKHAB2UANaY8AMyg4oAQyyyBAXSgQAHsmEATJQygB%20KIIBcUYRABuqFeZyquAXwDcXdyOQop88tACS3FDBUACCpkEhUQAapvLCIFxRTkkhAEIRqVHBAJpxCVlQKVEAwpnZIbHxiRW5%20TUhKSlcoJBQAOpwwAAW0WywiF4Y2PjEZJRU-vQcsQoJTkxuXFIArsKUcHii3RAICHhUgpraeuKSMp090UwAFK0Qppe9tFbyCCsPT9GqfADk0b8VABKUxWPBwHScdxOIA)